# Delete file after using response.download() in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, server, download, fs

I'm working on an app which has a server that downloads files to the client's device using `response.download()`. (I'm using node.js, express, and fs) Once these files are downloaded, they are just taking up space, so I've tried calling `fs.unlinksync` after the download to get rid of them. No such luck, though: I just get the following error: `NOENT: No such file or directory.`

Here is the relevant server-side code:

```
app.get("/file", function(request, response) {
  var filename = request.query.f;
  var filePath = "public/" + filename
  response.download(filePath);
//this is where I've tried putting fs.unlink
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`response.download` has a callback function, you can delete your file after download as below

```
response.download(filePath, yourFileName, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err); // Check error if you want
  }
  fs.unlink(yourFilePath, function(){
      console.log("File was deleted") // Callback
  });

  // fs.unlinkSync(yourFilePath) // If you don't need callback
});
```

Comment: I tried this and got `TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CALLBACK]: Callback must be a function`.

Comment: its not deleting file in given path.

Comment: This won't work in Chromium based mobile browsers as the user is prompt with a download option.

Answer (score 4):

`res.download()` is asynchronous.  That means it starts the operation and then returns so if you try to remove the file on the next line, the download operation won't have completed yet.  `res.download()` has an optional callback that will tell you when the operation is complete and you can remove the file in that callback.

```
app.get("/file", function(request, response) {
  var filename = request.query.f;
  var filePath = "public/" + filename
  response.download(filePath, {dotfiles: "deny"}, function(err) {
     // the operation is done here          
  });
});
```

Comment: @s.j - What foes this question or answer have to do with deleting a file?  If you have a question about deleting, please ask your own question.